# How to minimize traffic and load time for http request for external scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, optimization, httpresponse

So I was pretty interested in the idea of head.js, however the idea doesn't play nice with the way I have developed my backend.

Basically what I'm trying to do is decide how I should serve my scripts(js and css) giving my services the most performance and the least traffic. I feel like I can replicate a more integrated idea of head.js using more of my backend. I'm using node.js, without any frameworks around it, to serve everything.

MoreOver, I have several javascript and css files. Basically the idea is theres one for the entire site for the header, footer and reused methods and styles. Then there's one for each page.

The original idea was to make the server send a get request to "/js?src=" and just request one file like "index", then index will be all the javascript that is needed to load on that page will be sent as a single response as a big conjoined script. The problem with this is I'm using Closure Compiler and this just seems like I would run into a lot of issues with this except for the CSS.

The second idea is to create a loop in the template to create separate requests for each script. Utilizing more of the idea of head.js, however moving it to the backend.

The third idea, maybe I'm overthinking at this point. Create a Closure Compiled version of the scripts for each page which will include the javascript for not only the page but the header and footer, therefore the scripts never conflict. This creates redundant data in each of the files, and posses the issue of not pipelining my assets.

The basic idea of my service is a website that will serve social media content, images, and music in realtime. So initial page loading isn't extremely important, however, I want the server to be able to handle a large number of requests quickly. So I'm more focused on the big picture of serving many users than I am on the individual users experience. Whats my best approach?

Comment: The initial page load IS always important.  It's the first impression you give a new user.  May I suggest embedding the CSS in each page during production.  It's extra work, but the site serves quickly. Remember latency is the slow part not bandwidth (at least for most CSS files).  Then serve the JS using XHR.

Comment: I don't really understand why serving CSS embedded in the page would serve faster. Because its typically smaller than js? Won't it just create a larger initial page to serve? Am I getting to nitpicky? I feel like the idea of pipelining http requests for css and js is to allow the browser to load and start rendering the page while your javascript and css are loaded.

Comment: CSS/JS files are not loaded until the html is loaded and parsed by the browser. Also browsers don't load the CSS files, scripts, images all at the same time, they make up to X simultaneous requests to the same server. That's why people use sprites, or why embed CSS would make the site load faster (less requests, total bandwidth is the same).

Comment: TheBronx is right and I would add that often times the slowest path to rendering your page is latency (round trip times) not bandwidth.  On ATT 3G I see latency times of over 1.5 seconds while the time to send 20k is 100mS.  So, if you have 3 CSS files (header, body, and footer), that could add substantial time to the page load.  Even if some requests are made in parallel.